# Why doesn't GWT use gwt-dispatch?

Tags: gwt, command-pattern, gwt-dispatch

After looking into [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) and the [Google Wave I/O presentation (Best practices)](http://extgwt-mvp4g-gae.blogspot.com/2009/10/gwt-app-architecture-best-practices.html) ([video here](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html)), I'm wondering why the official GWT release (2.0) doesn't use dispatch (ie. the command pattern) for it's RPC calls. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GWT offers a basic way for calling service methods. You can use different patterns in conjunction with that. So if you just want a very simple service, with maybe a few methods that just take an Integer, and return a String - you can do that. If you want more, you can add gwt-dispatch or also something else easily.

This way, the GWT core stays simpler and cleaner, and the code size can be kept smaller for those who don't need that functionality. It's a modular approach.